# How to get certainly all lines of the unvisible text from a multiline textarea (overflow: hidden)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I want the text to continue from one div-container to another one. Both are css formated as overflow: hidden. So far it has not been possible for me to fix this exactly, to divide the text exactly at the word.

```
$(function() {
 var text = $("#text1").html();
 var height = $("#text1").height();
 var lineheight = $("div.text").height();
 var rows = Math.round(height / lineheight);

 var text1 = text.substring(
    text.indexOf(" ",Math.round(text.length / rows)));
 $('#text2').html($.trim(text1));

 });
```

Is there a possibility to get this accurately with dynamic text?
[Example in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/wMPjJ/357/)

Comment: Thank you, Pete, for your advice. But in my text are line breaks. Maybe this not work in css columns.

Comment: Sorry, didn't actually look at your fiddle, that is why you should create a [MCVE] in the question itself - as the off topic questions state: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: These line breaks are generally the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/wMPjJ/359/

Otherwise the multi-column layout would be a nice solution. I just now noticed that.